# See if the user looks at a GPS position

Tags: android, android-studio

Would it be possible to set up a specific GPS position in an App and then tell if the user is looking (holding his smartphone) at this direction? Can a rotation of the user to the left / right from that positions direction be read? (like "user looks 20 degrees to the left from the straight direction to the GPS point)[image: GPS target image]

Comment: You do not need GPS for left and right orientation, just use the compass sensor, you can combine GPS and compass or other sensor info to calculate direction and orientation

Comment: As far as I know the answer is you can not get orientation from GPS with out moving, you need to have some algorithm to calculate orientation while moving

Comment: So that would mean that I need to get the user position via GPS and his orientation via compass. Then I need to calculate a vector to see if the user is looking at this GPS point or not? (it is okay that the user needs to move / rotate)

Comment: That is correct, naturally you can use only GPS to give orientation but in that case the use needs to move and your algorithm should calculate the movement direction and return the direction. I will put my comments together and add few extra things and leave an answer, working on it.

Comment: let me know if I should leave a detailed answer or is it ok with the comments?

Comment: Thank you for your help so far, as I am really an Android Studio beginner, I would definitely appreciate a detailed answer to be honest :)
I see that there are some small articles about geo locational functions already, but they only cover the standard setup methods which would let me setup my GPS target point and get the user location, but not if the user looks TO that point and if not, how many degrees to the left or right away from it. I see this should be done with the magnetic or the gyroskop sensor. I am really curious to your detailed answer now :)

Comment: And of course with the answer, I would be able to mark this question as solved plus giving you credit for this, as no one seems to really be interested in this kind of topic. So all my hope lies in your hands now.. :D

Comment: Ok I left answer as your request, if you need more details you are welcome to comment and I will come back to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question, in your case GPS receiver is only collecting absolute location with margin (inaccurate) of 3-10 meter depending on your receiver type.
When your device returns the location of latitude and longitude, it does not know your orientation, if we assume you only use GPS, then the only way to calculate orientation is by movement the receiver (movement mean walking for while constantly).

To get your orientation typically using Magnetic Compass and/or Gyroscopes build in your device.

There are no final rules how to use this or that, what you need to do is to find out what is your requirement and make some tests to find the best results.

One disadvantage of using GPS constantly, is that it is power consuming (it drain the battery) so you need to make a strategy of combining differing sensors and turn on/off GPS programmatically to collecting data periodically.

And make algorithm logic to give the user the orientation regarding to the position.

I have provided some useful links:

- https://www.geolounge.com/absolute-relative-location/
- https://www.quora.com/Sensors/What-is-the-difference-between-accelerometers-gyroscopes-and-magnetometers
- http://www.explainthatstuff.com/howgpsworks.html
- http://www.tracklogs.co.uk/cgi-bin/publ/user.cgi?obj=support&mod=kbase&view=15885925
- [How do I programmatically find direction on a blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362025/how-do-i-programmatically-find-direction-on-a-blackberry)

Comment: This is really nice of you and provides me so much information and a good tip on what I have to consider when trying to do this, thank you so much!